# Checking if an array of items exist in a DynamoDB Python without looping

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, for-loop, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB with hashes as UserIDs and set as partition key.

I want to know whether an Item exists in the table or not.

I gonna pass an array of User-Hashes. Each Hash in this array should be checked whether it exists or not.

I already found a solution with `GetItem`. But that would mean, that i have to loop over all the User-Hashes in the array, right?

Does anybody has a solution how to do this without looping? Looping takes too much of the performance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no shortcut here. You could do parallel (multi-threaded client) calls to reduce the overall latency.